# Populating Database problem crossing tables

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm creating one small web app for practice, its Calories Counter. I created entities and now want to populate Mongo DB, but I have one problem and I'll try to explain best I can.

Just to notify in my main class I `implements CommandLineRunner` and then implement `run` method.

First I `@Autowired` my services.

```
@Autowired
FoodService foodService;
@Autowired
UserService userService;
@Autowired
HistoryService historyService;
```

Then I created this method to populate DB.

```
      @Override
      public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    HistoryDto historyDto1 = new HistoryDto();
    HistoryDto historyDto2 = new HistoryDto();
    UserDto userDto1 = new UserDto();
    UserDto userDto2 = new UserDto();
    FoodDto foodDto1 = new FoodDto();
    FoodDto foodDto2 = new FoodDto();

    HistoryDto savedHistory1 = historyService.save(historyDto1);
    HistoryDto savedHistory2 = historyService.save(historyDto2);
    UserDto savedUser1 = userService.save(userDto1);
    UserDto savedUser2 = userService.save(userDto2);
    FoodDto savedFood1 = foodService.save(foodDto1);
    FoodDto savedFood2 = foodService.save(foodDto2);


    userDto1.setUsername("John");
    userDto1.setHistoryId(savedHistory1.getHistoryId());


    userDto2.setUsername("Marc");
    userDto2.setHistoryId(savedHistory2.getHistoryId());

    foodDto1.setName("HotDog");
    foodDto1.setDescription("Very HOT DOG");
    foodDto1.setCalories(99);

    foodDto2.setName("Burger");
    foodDto2.setDescription("Very Burger");
    foodDto2.setCalories(230);


    historyDto1.setFoodId(savedUser1.getFoodId());
    historyDto1.setTotalCalories(savedFood1.getCalories());
    historyDto1.setUserId(savedUser1.getUserId());

    historyDto2.setFoodId(savedUser2.getFoodId());
    historyDto2.setTotalCalories(savedFood2.getCalories());
    historyDto2.setUserId(savedUser2.getUserId());
```

As expected, no errors, database is created but my collections stays empty because I first save entities and then initialize data.

As you can see, `History` has `savedFood` and `savedUser`so If I first initialize `History` like this:

```
    historyDto1.setFoodId(savedUser1.getFoodId());
    historyDto1.setTotalCalories(savedFood1.getCalories());
    historyDto1.setUserId(savedUser1.getUserId());

    historyDto2.setFoodId(savedUser2.getFoodId());
    historyDto2.setTotalCalories(savedFood2.getCalories());
    historyDto2.setUserId(savedUser2.getUserId());
```

Then create variable to save it like this:

```
    HistoryDto savedHistory1 = historyService.save(historyDto1);
    HistoryDto savedHistory2 = historyService.save(historyDto2);
```

Im getting errors for `savedUser1` and `savedFood1` as expected.

And If I put user below that like this so part of code now stays like:

```
    userDto1.setUsername("John");
    userDto1.setHistoryId(savedHistory1.getHistoryId());


    userDto2.setUsername("Marc");
    userDto2.setHistoryId(savedHistory2.getHistoryId());

    historyDto1.setFoodId(savedUser1.getFoodId());
    historyDto1.setTotalCalories(savedFood1.getCalories());
    historyDto1.setUserId(savedUser1.getUserId());

    historyDto2.setFoodId(savedUser2.getFoodId());
    historyDto2.setTotalCalories(savedFood2.getCalories());
    historyDto2.setUserId(savedUser2.getUserId());

    HistoryDto savedHistory1 = historyService.save(historyDto1);
    HistoryDto savedHistory2 = historyService.save(historyDto2);
```

I'm getting error on `userDto1.setHistoryId(savedHistory1.getHistoryId());` logic, because now `savedHistory1` is not resolved.

How I can fix this. I tried to add collection by collection but then, for example If I created `Food` collection and now want to create `History` I cant call `foodId` to store in `History`.

I tried to explain best I can, and sorry for bad English, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fresher, I'm not showing optimized code, but I will solve you with the same code you tried. I'm not sure, why you are saving cyclic way like userId in History and history id in User (but mongodb allows it).
Ok, lets come to the solution. I used default ObjectId, sometime you might haved used any data type. Code works top to bottom. You dont need to save at first. Once your business logic is finished, you can save

```
FoodDto foodDto1 = new FoodDto();
foodDto1.setName("HotDog");
foodDto1.setDescription("Very HOT DOG");
foodDto1.setCalories(99);
FoodDto savedFood1 = foodService.save(foodDto1);

UserDto userDto1 = new UserDto();
userDto1.setUsername("John");
userDto1.setHistoryId(savedHistory1.getId());
UserDto savedUser1 = userService.save(userDto1); 

HistoryDto historyDto1 = new HistoryDto();
historyDto1.setFoodId(savedFood1.getId());
historyDto1.setTotalCalories(savedFood1.getCalories());
historyDto1.setUserId(savedUser1.getId());
HistoryDto savedHistory1 = historyService.save(historyDto1);
```

And your respective classes

```
public class FootDto{
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int calories;
}

public class UserDto{
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String username;
    private ObjectId historyId;
}

public class HistoryDto{
    @Id
    private ObjectId _id;
    private ObjectId foodId;
    private int totalCalories;
    private ObjectId userId;
}
```